# Can not download vcpkg by git

Tags: git, powershell, vcpkg

When I use git to download the vcpkg, it said Unsupported proxy syntax in':'

I use following command on powershell:

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
```

and it returns:

```
fatal:unable to access 'https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git': Unsupported proxy syntax in '<host>:<port>'
```

My laptop should not have any proxy setting, as well as the git. 
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: `set | grep -Fi _proxy`? `git config -l | grep -Fi _proxy`?

Comment: Are these commend to git bash? set | grep -Fi _proxy returns HTTPS_PROXY='<host>:<port>' HTTP_PROXY='<host>:<port>' no_proxy="<domain>'

Comment: git config -l | grep -Fi _proxy returns

error:unknown switch '1'
usage:git config[<options>]

Comment: Yes............

Comment: It's lowercase `L` (ell) not `1` (one).

Comment: nothing happend after I enter git config -l | grep -Fi _proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have environment variables `HTTPS_PROXY='<host>:<port>'` and `HTTP_PROXY='<host>:<port>'`. If you do not have proxy unset them in the current terminal:

```
unset HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY
```

and remove from the shell config file(s). Search them in `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you! once I found them and delete them in the environment variables, and finally works!

Comment: but i am not sure where to get the shell config file(s)

Comment: `~` means `$HOME`